# How to apply visibility filter to category view's product collection in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, product-collection, magento2.2

How do I apply setVisibility() to 'Not Visible Individually' in Category view's collection?

Basically, I want to load products with visibility 'Not Visible Individually' only for a specific category. The product with visibility 'Not Visible Individually' is assigned to multiple categories, but when viewing those categories this product should be visible only for a specific category and not for the rest of the categories.

So, what I want is to know how to apply this visibility filter in category view's product collection, whether its by plugin, observer or override.

Comment: Hi, did you solve that? Looking for the same :) TY!

Answer (score 0):

If you have collection you must add filter like below:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->setVisibility([1]);
```